# Thread end listener. Java

Tags: java, multithreading, actionlistener

Are there any Listeners in Java to handle that some thread have been ended?
Something like this:

```
Future<String> test = workerPool.submit(new TestCalalble());
test.addActionListener(new ActionListener()               
   {                                                         
    public void actionEnd(ActionEvent e)               
    {                                                        
        txt1.setText("Button1 clicked");                        
    }                                                        
   });
```

I know, that it is impossible to deal like this, but I want to be notified when some thread ended.

Usually I used for this Timer class with checking state of each Future. but it is not pretty way.
Thanks

Answer (score 13):

There is [CompletionService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html) you can use.

```
CompletionService<Result> ecs
       = new ExecutorCompletionService<Result>(e);
ecs.submit(new TestCallable());
if (ecs.take().get() != null) {
    // on finish
}
```

Another alternative is to use [ListenableFuture](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) from Guava.

Code example:

```
ListenableFuture future = Futures.makeListenable(test);
future.addListener(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
   System.out.println("Operation Complete.");
   try {
     System.out.println("Result: " + future.get());
   } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Error: " + e.message());
   }
 }
}, exec);
```

Personally, I like Guava solution better.

Comment: Good to know. I am not using Guava but it seems that I should.

Comment: well... how to put this. You should. Really. :)

Comment: "take()  - Retrieves and removes the Future representing the next completed task, waiting if none are yet present.@" But I want to work asynchronously, so it does not fit

Comment: +1 for Guava. Yes, you should absolutely use it. Great tools.

Comment: @Denis, then I think... ListenableFuture is for you

Comment: @nanda, thanks alot. I'll try to override afterExecute() method from ThreadPoolExecutor, if it would not work like I want, I'll try ListenableFuture.

Comment: makeListenable() is deprecated and even deleted now: _"Prefer to create ListenableFuture instances with SettableFuture, MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator( java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService), ListenableFutureTask, AbstractFuture, and other utilities over creating plain Future instances to be upgraded to ListenableFuture after the fact. If this is not possible, the functionality of makeListenable is now available as JdkFutureAdapters.listenInPoolThread(java.util.concurrent.Future)."_

Answer (score 3):

No. Such listener does not exist.
But you have 2 solutions.

1. Add code that notifies you that thread is done in the end of `run()` method
2. Use `Callable` interface that returns result of type `Future`. You can ask Future what the status is and use blocked method `get()` to retrieve result

Comment: Also I can override afterExecute() method from ThreadPoolExecutor class.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a *geekish*  listener. Highly unadvisible to use but, funny and clever

```
Thread t = ...
t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler(){
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        t.getThreadGroup().uncaughtException(t, e);//this is the default behaviour
    }       
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable{
        //cool, we go notified
      //handle the notification, but be worried, it's the finalizer thread w/ max priority
    }
});
```

The effect can be achived via PhantomRefernce better

hope you have a little smile :)

---

Side note: what you ask is *NOT thread end*, but task completion event and the best is overriding either `decorateTask` or `afterExecute`

Answer (score 3):

You can implement Observer Pattern to report completion.

```
public interface IRunComplete {
    public void reportCompletion(String message);
}
```

Let the Thread caller implement this interface.

and in run() method you call this method at the end. So now you exactly knows when this thread gonna end.

Try it. I am actually using this and it's working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Without adding a lot of extra code you can make a quick listener thread yourself as follows:

```
//worker thread for doings
Thread worker = new Thread(new Runnable(){ 
    public void run(){/*work thread stuff here*/}
});
worker.start();
//observer thread for notifications
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
    try{worker.join();}
    catch(Exception e){;}
    finally{ /*worker is dead, do notifications.*/}
}).start();
```

Comment: I was unable to call .start.() in the new thread call (new Thread(new Runnable(){   )

Answer (score 1):

You have a join() method defined by Thread class for that. However, you don't have direct visibility to a thread executing your Callable in concurrency API case..

Comment: I tried to answer the question as it is: "Are there any Listeners in **Java** to handle that some **thread** have been ended?" without going into j.u.c. or Guava or anything else built on top of the core languauge.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this Example:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CompletionListener completedListener = count -> System.out.println("Final Count Value: " + count);

        HeavyWorkRunnable job = new HeavyWorkRunnable(completedListener);

        Thread otherThread = new Thread(job);
        otherThread.start();

    }

    static class HeavyWorkRunnable implements Runnable {

        CompletionListener completionListener;

        public HeavyWorkRunnable(CompletionListener completionListener) {
            this.completionListener = completionListener;
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {

            int count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Clock Tick #"+i);

                count += 1;

            }

            if (completionListener != null) {
                completionListener.onCompleted(count);
            }
        }
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface CompletionListener {

        void onCompleted(int count);

    }
}
```